# the problem with saving data from the database to the data model

Tags: android, flutter

The problem is that I get data from two requests in one method and I need to save this data in the Message and User models, but saving occurs only if one request is saved to the model, if the second one is connected, then it will not work. Saving to two different models together does not happen! If you do not save anything at all in the model, then the data in the Streambuilder is output correctly! The problem is that it is not possible to save from two queries to two models at the same time! What could be the problem?

```
void fetchMessages() async {
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
int? userId = prefs.getInt('user_id');

Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 3), (timer) async {
  try {
    // Ожидание результатов обоих запросов
    var results = await Future.wait([
      http.post(
        Uri.parse(API.GetMessageChat),
        body: {
          'UserId': userId.toString(),
        },
      ),
      http.post(Uri.parse(API.GetUserInfo), body: {
        'user_ids': jsonEncode(['163', '156']),
      }),
    ]);

    var response1 = results[0];
    var response2 = results[1];

    List<Message> messages = [];
    List<User> users = [];

    if (response1.statusCode == 200) {
      List<dynamic> messageData = jsonDecode(response1.body);
      messages = messageData.map((json) => Message.fromJson(json)).toList();
      print("Messages: $messages");
    }

    if (response2.statusCode == 200) {
      List<dynamic> userData = jsonDecode(response2.body);
      users = (userData as List).map((json) => User.fromJson(json)).toList();
      print("Users: $users");
    }

    // Объединяем результаты обоих запросов и добавляем в соответствующие потоки
    _messageStreamController.add(messages);
    _userListStreamController.add(users);
  } catch (e) {
    // Обработка ошибок
  }
});
```

}